# The force involved in magnetic attraction

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, charge, ferromagnetism

Magnetic field causes a force to act on moving charges as in this equation:  $F = qv*B$. So what is the force that causes a magnet to attract a charge-less piece of iron? or causes the like poles of two magnets to repel each other?

Comment: A magnetic dipole also applies forces on other magnetic dipoles due to its field

Answer (score 1):

It is the magnetic force between magnets. It is very similar to magnetic force between electric circuits carrying electric currents, where this force can be explained as consequence of the Lorentz force $q\mathbf v\times \mathbf B$. One can model the magnet either as a set of current loops (the Ampere magnetic model) or a set of magnetic dipoles (the Coulomb magnetic model). In either case, the force between magnets is basic force of nature and we call it magnetic force.